# Does 被【かぶ】る have any relation to "cover"?

Tags: words, etymology, colloquial-language, loanwords, folklore

Topic.  I've heard/seen somewhere that `被【かぶ】る` was "gairaigo-fied" (?) from the English word "cover"  (similar to `ダブる` or `デモる`), and then presumably given ateji from `被【おお】う` since the meanings overlap so much.  I searched several dictionaries for some sort of verification but have found nothing so far.  Is there any truth to this?

Comment: “Is there any truth to this?”  No.  Someone with the access to 日本国語大辞典 can probably show a quote from around the year 1200 (which I can only guess from the [excerpt at Yahoo!辞書](http://dic.search.yahoo.co.jp/search?p=%E3%81%8B%E3%81%B6%E3%82%8B&ei=UTF-8)).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As Tsuyoshi says, there is no truth to it. The earliest reference given in the [日]{に}[本]{ほん}[国]{こく}[語]{ご}[大]{だい}[辞]{じ}[典]{てん} is from the mid-13th century [観]{かん}[智]{じ}[院]{いん}[本]{ぼん} edition of the [[類]{るい}[聚]{じゅ}[名]{みょう}[義]{ぎ}[抄]{しょう}](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E9%A1%9E%E8%81%9A%E5%90%8D%E7%BE%A9%E6%8A%84):

> 盖 オホフ カフル

Even English barely had the word [cover](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=cover) at that point.

Also, according to the same dictionary, `かぶる` is derived from `かがふる`, which is even older--It's in the Man'yōshū (9C):

> [可]{か}[之]{し}[古]{こ}[伎]{き}[夜]{や} / [美]{み}[許]{こ}[等]{と} [加]{か}[我]{が}[布]{ふ}[理]{り} / ...

Comment: @Matt: Can you provide furigana for 観智院本名義抄, and maybe say what it is? I can't determine the correct reading just be looking at it. Nor does it come up right away in a Google search.

Comment: @DaveMG There you go.