# Mnemonic to remember different "to wear" verbs

Tags: verbs, mnemonics

Does anyone have suggestions for a mnemonic or other memory device for the different verbs meaning "to wear" in 日本語?

```
かぶる (kaburu) - hat / headwear
着る (kiru) - Tops / jackets and all-over clothes
履く (haku) - Bottoms and shoes
かける (kakeru) - Glasses and sunglasses
つける (tsukeru) - Perfume / cologne
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- **Headwear**: [*kaburu* sounds a bit like English "cover"](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/3558/78).
- **Tops**: Traditionally, upper-torso coverings in Japan were robe-like, where the hems of the two sides "cut across".  This helped me remember when I was studying, as "cut" in Japanese is the other *kiru*.  :)
- **Bottoms and footwear**: One of the other *haku* verbs in Japanese is 掃く "to sweep", a bit like the sweeping motion of pants as you pull them on.  Alternatively, think about the verb *hiku*, "to pull", perhaps adding in the あ from the idea of "pulling **on**".
- **Glasses**: You *kakeru* something when it **catches** on something else, like a lock **catching** on the doorframe to keep a door shut, or a wall hanging **catching** on the hook when you hang it up.  Glasses similarly **catch** onto your ears.
- **Perfume**: *tsukeru* can be thought of as **sticking** something into or onto something else.  I find this one might be easier to remember if you think about dabbing scent with a finger, as opposed to using a spray bottle, since you physically **stick** the scent onto your body.

Comment: @istrasci - Thank you, knowing the literal definitions certainly makes the reason for, and remembering the words, much easier.

Answer (score 1):

Some of the literal definitions of かける are "to hang", "suspend", or "hook".  This should be easy to remember for glasses (easier, I think, than thinking of "catching").

Comment: FWIW, the initial `/ka/` in "catch (onto)" and _kakeru_ was how I remembered the various shades of meaning.  Your point is a good one, and I'm certainly a fan of having more tools in the toolbox, so +1.  :)

Comment: @EiríkrÚtlendi:  Agreed.  And I wasn't meaning to speak negatively of your answer.  Hope it wasn't received that way.

Comment: No worries, not at all!  :)

Answer (score 1):

For those that know what a [kimono](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kimono) and [hakama](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hakama) (a kind of traditional lower-body garment) are, you can see how they match with kiru and haku to clarify those two verbs.

Just adding to the answer, it was great already (and the first search hit).