# Difference between 着用する and 着る

Tags: meaning, wago-and-kango

As the title says, what is the difference between these two words? Do they both mean "to wear [clothes]"? When would it be appropriate to use one over the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- 着用する is more formal because it's a Sino-Japanese word. 着用する is almost never used in daily conversations. It is typically used in formal invitation letters, scientific articles, etc.
- 着る is only for something you put on like shirts. 着用する can be generically used also with socks, skirts, hats, glasses, necklaces, etc. (But please don't overuse 着用!)

See Also

- [Is there a general/default word for "to wear"?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/4965/5010)
- [Mnemonic to remember different "to wear" verbs](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/50300/5010)